# Does MariaDB JDBC driver use NO_SCHEMA parameter internally?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I needed to change database to query so i used `setSchema()` method of `Connection` object but it didn't work and i found `setCatalog()` method and yes it worked.

```java
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
connection.setSchema(schema); // not working
connection.setCatalog(schema); // working
```

I found that in MySQL and probably in MariaDB as well the term `catalog` and `schema` means the same thing which is database in this case and there is connection parameters which term would activate such as `NO_SCHEMA` and `NO_CATALOG`.

I could see that those parameters are listed in [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html) page so i thought there is similar page in MariaDB as well but still no luck.

I want to know what makes `setCatalog()` works and `setSchema()` doesn't. Please let me know if there is resource about it.

Comment: That’s an ODBC document. It isn’t mentioned in the JDBC connector document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `useCatalogTerm` exists in MariaDB as well. Documentation https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/ was missing that option, and that is just corrected now.

Note that setting option useCatalogTerm to schema (i.e., connection string like `jdbc:mariadb://host/db?useCatalogTerm=schema`) will not only add use of connection.setSchema(schema) in place of connection.setCatalog(schema) but will also impact metadata use: for example `DatabaseMetaData.getSchemas(String catalog, String schemaPattern)`